# Different outputs with format specifiers in C

Tags: c++, c, printf, scanf

```
int x;
scanf("%d",&x);
printf("%d",x);

Input: . (just a period)
Output: 4096
```

Why does it output 4096 here.  Here is what I am thinking: So the ASCII value of a period is 46.  Upon input, it reads in x as the bit pattern for 46? And when it prints, does it print out four bytes at the memory location of x, so only the first byte is filled with the bit pattern corresponding to 46, and the rest is random stuff that makes up the 4096?  But this is incorrect, because look what happens when I do this--

```
int x;
scanf("%d",&x);
printf("%c",x);

Input: . (period)
Output: (nothing)

Input: 46
Output: . (period)
```

Even more confusing is what is going on when I do this:

```
int x;
scanf("%c",&x);
printf("%d",x);

Input: . (period)
Output: 4142

Input: 46
Output: 4148

Input: 47
Output: 4148
```

Comment: What happens if you initialize `x` to some value, and/or check the return value from `scanf` to see how many arguments it successfully assigned?

Comment: @ordinary - What do you want it to print? Why do you think it would print that?

Comment: The format string must match the type of `x`, otherwise the result  is undefined. And if you don't check the return value of `scanf` you don't now if it actually read anything.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to check the return value of scanf (it's the count of successfully read values):

```
int x;

if (scanf("%d",&x) == 1) {
    printf("%d", x);
} else {
    printf("Invalid input.");
}
```

If the parsing failed, the value of x is not defined.

Once `scanf` has failed, further calls will also fail because the invalid input is not removed from the stream. Because of this it is not a good idea to use `scanf`.

Comment: Exactly. He can test it just by removing the scanf call, it will probably print the same number.

Comment: *"Because of this it is not a good idea to use scanf. In C++ it is better to use input streams:"* -- I don't follow your logic here.  Input streams have the same issue.  You need to check the state of the stream to check if the values were successfully read, and once input to a stream has failed, further calls will also fail.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley: Sorry - that part is now removed.